# RunLength Decoding in C

Tags: c, pointers, char, run-length-encoding

This is my program for RunLength Decoding. But is is giving output as garbage values. The output in the `char *decode_rle(char *a,int length)` method is correct, but when it is returned to the main function it is wrong.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char *decode_rle(char *a,int length)
{
    char op[50];
    int i,j,k=0,count=0;
    for(i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        if( a[i]=='a' || a[i]=='b' || a[i]=='c' || a[i]=='d' || a[i]=='e' || a[i]=='f' || a[i]=='g')
        {
            count = a[i+1] - '0';
            for(j=0;j<count;j++)
            {
                op[k]=a[i];
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
    op[k] = '\0';
printf("\n the decoded string is %s\n",op);
    return op;
}
int main()
{
    int i=0,j,length,count;
    char a[20],*output;
    printf("\n Enter a string ");
    gets(a);
    printf("\n The string you entered is %s",a);
    length = strlen(a);
    printf("\n length is %d\n",length);
    output = decode_rle(a,length);
    i=0;
    while(output[i]!='\0')
    {
        printf("%c",output[i]);
        i++;
   }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, replace `gets` with `fgets`.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you are returning a pointer to a local variable of function decode_rle which does not exist anymore once you return from that function.

to start, i suggest you declare op as local variable of main and pass an extra parameter to decode_rle.

```
char *decode_rle(char *a,int length, char *op)
{
    ....
}

int main()
{
    ...
    char op[50];
   ...

    output = decode_rle(a,length, op);
}
```

this will work, but...there several other problems in this excercise if you need it for more than a limited proof of concept.

- you are using fixed lengths for a and p, what happens if the user enters a string longer than 20 in gets? what if the decoded string is larger than 50?
  (remember that c does not do array bounds checkings, what happens if you write on memory you don't own?)
- how do you deal with binary 0 ? (remember, strings in c are stored using asciiz convention, what happens if the data your are trying to compress/decompress contains itself binary 0s? how would you change the definition of the buffers to handle this situation?)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to return a variable whose scope is only the function `decode_rle`. You can't do that and be safe. When you exit the function, the array `op` and its contents are no longer *officially* accessible to your program

You should compile with warnings `-Wall` (and you could add in `-Werror` to motivate you a bit).

Answer (score 0):

You return a pointer to `op`, which is a local variable in `decode_rle()`. This local variable goes out of scope when the function returns and its memory will get reused, so a pointer to that memory is not very useful.

Instead you could either allocate the required memory with `malloc()` and return a pointer to that, or add an additional parameter to `decode_rle()` where you pass a pointer to memory where the result should be written to.